# StreamInputFormat for mapreduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I have an application that connects to a remote system and transfers data from it using sftp protocol. I want to use a mapreduce job to do the same. I would need a input format that reads from an input stream . I have been going through the docs for HStreamInputFormat and StreamInputFormat but my hadoop-2.0 doesnt seem to support these classes . How do I proceed ? Any links to tutorials or examples of reading from input streams using input formats ?

Answer (score 0):

If those SteamInputFormats doesn't support your need then you better off writing your own InputFormat with your customized needs. Please read [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#inputformat) tutorial to learn how to write your own custom InputFormat and RecordReader.

Comment: Thanks :) Cant write a InputFormat here because I don't know how to handle input streams as path to mapper and hadoop doen't have any base classes in place .